# How to change the image path in Tinymce

Tags: php, image, tinymce

When I'm uploading a image it stored in the path that I defined (pnetwork/images/tiny)in my config.php file as in the folowing image
[image]

But when I changed the path to "http://domainName.com/pnetwork/images/tiny" it gives error.
Please give me solution i need the full path

Comment: Also in the same way i want to set default path for smiley images path in tinymce

Answer (score 1):

Check the following links

[Dynamically set TinyMCE file path for file browser and image viewier using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367026/dynamically-set-tinymce-file-path-for-file-browser-and-image-viewier-using-php)

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.Editor

You should check the image_path value in tinymce.js file

Comment: This is not what i required. Will you tell me the place where i need to change the path

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set domain name by preview.urlprefix parameter
[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager:preview.urlprefix](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager%3apreview.urlprefix)

You can set this parameter in config file or dynamically by code.
So you need have something like this in config file:

With this setting domain name should add to pictures that was added by tinyMCE image manager

Answer (score 1):

why dont you to use latest download from http://www.tinymce.com/
it has all options with demos